# How to prevent camera from clipping through floor? (UPBGE)

Tags: objects, 3d-view, game-engine, camera, physics

I have added a camera with a spherical empty to my model to view all angles, but the problem is that when I look up (during gameplay), the camera ends up below the floor (due to parenting), hence obscuring vision. Is there a way to prevent the camera from going through the floor? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the camera view from being obscured by sending a raycast from the camera to check if any object/mesh is in-front of, or behind the camera view, which is the Z-axis of the camera.

Here's a great tutorial exampling how to create and implement such a camera raycast for camera collision.

## Tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jim9W8B1KhU

Comment: I have actually tried this one in the past but it didn't work for some reason. I found another file with a setup that works for me anyways. Thanks.

Comment: Ah I forgot that Cotaks already gave you that blend on BA. My mistake.